# Express $\arccos x+ \arccos \left(\frac{x}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{3}-3x^2}{2}\right)$ in simplest form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Express $$\arccos x+ \arccos \left(\frac{x}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{3}-3x^2}{2}\right)$$ in simplest form.

I tried applying the direct formula but, that gave a very complicated equation. Converting it into a trigonometric ratio also seemed complex. How should I try to solve it?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What is “the direct formula”?

Comment: It's arc cos(xy+√(1-x^2)√(1-y^2))

Comment: @user473333 You should put that in your question using MathJax markdown.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\arccos x=t\implies0\le t\le\pi$ (Check for [principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values))

and $x=\cos t,\sin t=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$\dfrac x2+\dfrac{\sqrt3\sqrt{1-x^2}}2=\cos\left(t-\dfrac\pi3\right)$

Now $\arccos\left(\dfrac x2+\dfrac{\sqrt3\sqrt{1-x^2}}2\right)=\begin{cases}t-\dfrac\pi3\text{ iff }0\le t-\dfrac\pi3\le\pi\iff\dfrac\pi3\le t\le\pi+\dfrac\pi3\\=-\left(t-\dfrac\pi3\right)\text{  iff }0\le\dfrac\pi3-t\le\pi\iff?\end{cases} $